# UI not updating after binding the ItemsSource

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dispatcher, itemssource

i am binding an `ItemsSource` from a `ObservableCollection` with code below

```
Services.RestServices.GetNotifications(UserID, ++Page).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
              {
                setNotListToBind(task.Result).ContinueWith(t =>
                  {
                      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                           {
                            var list = getFilteredNotList(notList, NotificationCategories.requests);
                            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => NotificationContainer.ItemsSource = list;);
                           }));
                  });
              }));
        });
```

in above code i am using `task-parallel-library` to wait the excecution and within it i am binding the `itemsSource` with the `dispature`, but the `UI` not updating after binding.
here my `itemsSource` is `NotificationContainer` and the `ObservableCollection` is `list`

Answer (score 0):

If you know `Services.RestServices.GetNotifications` is being called from the UI thread, you could simplify the code by specifying the `TaskScheduler` instance on each call to `ContinueWith` using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSyncronizationContext`. Perhaps this can lead you closer to finding the issue.